# SharedPreferences all along the app is not storing the values

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am using SharedPreferences all along my app.

I am defining two types of them. One is called:

```
public static String MISDATOS= "MisDatos";
SharedPreferences prefs2 = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(MISDATOS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

and the other is called:

```
public static String MIPACIENTE= "MiPaciente";
 SharedPreferences prefs3 = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(MIPACIENTE, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

In the app there is a sequence of fragments that work as a long form used by the app user to introduce several information.

I have found an issue that makes me crazy at the moment.

There are Fragment 1, Fragment 2.... Fragment 10.

To make my issue more easy to understand, I will give you an example.

There is one of the sharepreferences item called:

```
Integer hayFotos =  prefs3.getInt("hayFotos",0);
```

To follow the sequence, at app start, its value is 0

At Fragment 1 first run, its value is obviously 0.

At Fragment 1, the user takes a picture or loads a picture from the gallery, than this fragment updates "hayFotos" value to 1.

Then Fragment 2 is called.

I have verified, that at first run fro Fragment 2, the value for "hayFotos" is 1, as it should be.

At Fragment 2 the user takes another picture and the value is updated to 2, it works.

At Fragment 3, the value is 2.

At Fragment 4, the value is 2.

At Fragment 5, the value is 0 again.

I have checked that I am taking the right getSharedPreferences key at every Fragment, but the Fragments in the sequence after Fragment 4 are losing its values for "hayFotos".

I could post here all the code to demonstrate that there is no error in the code that explains the value 0 for "hayFotos" after Fragment 4, but I would ask you first if there is a known explanation or it is surely a mistake in my code

EDIT:

I am going to put here the code and the debugger output to demonstrate my issue:

Code in fragment 1:

```
 SharedPreferences prefs5 =  getActivity().getSharedPreferences("MiPaciente", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        Integer num_buscado = prefs5.getInt("hayFotos",0);
        Log.d("Eva","Eva NE 1 "+num_buscado);
```

Output in Fragment 1

```
2020-05-01 16:58:38.076 11621-11621/com.mpidesarrollo.capenergy D/Eva: Eva NE 1 0
```

Code in Fragment 2:

```
SharedPreferences prefs5 =  getActivity().getSharedPreferences("MiPaciente", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        Integer num_buscado = prefs5.getInt("hayFotos",0);
        Log.d("Eva","Eva NE 2 "+num_buscado);
```

Output in Fragment 2:

```
2020-05-01 16:58:38.076 11621-11621/com.mpidesarrollo.capenergy D/Eva: Eva NE 1 0
2020-05-01 17:00:21.007 11621-11621/com.mpidesarrollo.capenergy D/Eva: Eva NE 2 0
```

I am taking a picture in Fragment 2.

Code in Fragment 3:

SharedPreferences prefs5 =  getActivity().getSharedPreferences("MiPaciente", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    Integer num_buscado = prefs5.getInt("hayFotos",0);
    Log.d("Eva","Eva NE 3 "+num_buscado);

Output in Fragment 3:

```
2020-05-01 16:58:38.076 11621-11621/com.mpidesarrollo.capenergy D/Eva: Eva NE 1 0
2020-05-01 17:00:21.007 11621-11621/com.mpidesarrollo.capenergy D/Eva: Eva NE 2 0
2020-05-01 17:01:58.273 11621-11621/com.mpidesarrollo.capenergy D/Eva: Eva NE 3 1
```

Code in Fragment 4:

```
   SharedPreferences prefs5 =  getActivity().getSharedPreferences("MiPaciente", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        Integer num_buscado = prefs5.getInt("hayFotos",0);
        Log.d("Eva","Eva NE 4 "+num_buscado);
```

Output in Fragment 4:

```
2020-05-01 16:58:38.076 11621-11621/com.mpidesarrollo.capenergy D/Eva: Eva NE 1 0
2020-05-01 17:00:21.007 11621-11621/com.mpidesarrollo.capenergy D/Eva: Eva NE 2 0
2020-05-01 17:01:58.273 11621-11621/com.mpidesarrollo.capenergy D/Eva: Eva NE 3 1
2020-05-01 17:03:38.238 11621-11621/com.mpidesarrollo.capenergy D/Eva: Eva NE 4 1
```

Code in Fragment 5:

```
 SharedPreferences prefs5 =  getActivity().getSharedPreferences("MiPaciente", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        Integer num_buscadoMiPaciente = prefs5.getInt("hayFotos",0);
        Log.d("Eva","Eva NT 1 MiPaciente "+num_buscadoMiPaciente);
        SharedPreferences prefs6 =  getActivity().getSharedPreferences("MisDatos", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        Integer num_buscadoMisDatos = prefs6.getInt("hayFotos",0);
        Log.d("Eva","Eva NT 1 MisDatos "+num_buscadoMisDatos);
```

Output in Fragment 5:

```
2020-05-01 16:58:38.076 11621-11621/com.mpidesarrollo.capenergy D/Eva: Eva NE 1 0
2020-05-01 17:00:21.007 11621-11621/com.mpidesarrollo.capenergy D/Eva: Eva NE 2 0
2020-05-01 17:01:58.273 11621-11621/com.mpidesarrollo.capenergy D/Eva: Eva NE 3 1
2020-05-01 17:03:38.238 11621-11621/com.mpidesarrollo.capenergy D/Eva: Eva NE 4 1
2020-05-01 17:04:59.547 11621-11621/com.mpidesarrollo.capenergy D/Eva: Eva NE 1 1
2020-05-01 17:04:59.585 11621-11621/com.mpidesarrollo.capenergy D/Eva: Eva NT 1 MiPaciente 0
2020-05-01 17:04:59.586 11621-11621/com.mpidesarrollo.capenergy D/Eva: Eva NT 1 MisDatos 0
```

Comment: Maybe it could be useful to look at the code that sets the value. For instance, you could be setting an outdated value to the preferences upon back navigation.

Answer (score 0):

You save your data in the `Activity` context not the Application context
Change `getActivity().getSharedPreferences(...)` to
  `getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(..)`

Comment: let me try, if you are right, you are making my day

Comment: It is not working, I have tried both methods but same result

Comment: I have also changed the activity that is taking the pictures from  prefs = this.getSharedPreferences(MIPACIENTE, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);  to prefs = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(MIPACIENTE, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

Comment: I am completelly lost now